# Printing the date out of number

Tags: javascript, date

I have a long numbber in array in javascript. It was taken from getTime(), but now its not an Date object.

```
tab[0][1]=1373139837555;// not date object - just int
```

And now I want to print it like this

Hour:Minute:Seconds | Day/Month/Year

Is there any function to print date?
I know the functions getHours(), getMinutes(), getTime(), but they only work for Date objects. Can I turn this long number to date? How can I print the date otherwise?

EDIT

This is my code with javascript and JQ

```
$.date = function (dateObject) {
    var d = new Date(dateObject);
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getSeconds();

    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    var date = hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+"||"+day+"/"+month+"/"+year;

    return date;
};

tab[0][1]=1373139837555;
console.log('Number '+$.date(tab[0][1]));
```

And it returns Number NaN:NaN:NaN || NaN/NaN/NaN :(
When I chech the tab[0][1] with is NaN it returns false - so it is a number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: @Juhana: Though I voted for closing as well, it's not an exact duplicate: Unix timestamps are in seconds and need to be multiplied by 1000 - a timestamp coming from `getTime` doesn't

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/46zKR/ (other than the month being off by one). Are you *really* sure the variable contains the number? If you do `console.log(tab[0][1])` you get the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a new date object using your long number (if I am not mistaken, this is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970)

```
tab[0][1]=1373139837555;

var date = new Date(tab[0][1]);
```

You can then get the day, month, etc using the functions you mention:

```
var printDate = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds() + 
                ' | ' + 
                date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a Date

```
new Date(1373139837555)
```

Comment: my mistake - Simon beat me to it and did it correctly. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To convert it to Date, just try this¨

```
var myDate = new Date(tab[0][1]);
```

Once is converted, use getHours(), getMinutes(), getTime(), etc.

Comment: So I should just write tab[0][1]=new Date(tab[0][1]) ?